# Notify ViewModel when View's RenderTransformProperty changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a two-way binding on the `UIElement` `RenderTransformProperty`.  Connecting from the `ViewModel` to the `View` works fine, and the `ViewModel` can read an updated value from the `View`, but the `ViewModel` is not aware when the property in the `View` changes. I know I could create my own `DependencyProperty` and shuttle the value but it seems wrong.  How do I properly notify the `ViewModel` when the `View's` `RenderTransformProperty` changes.

In the View:

```
var renderTransformBinding = new Binding
{
  Path = new PropertyPath("SymbolTransform"),
  Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
};
SetBinding(RenderTransformProperty, renderTransformBinding);
```

In the ViewModel (using MVVM Light):

```
private Transform _symbolTransform;
public Transform SymbolTransform
{
    get { return _symbolTransform; }
    set
    {
        if (Set(() => SymbolTransform, ref _symbolTransform, value))
        {
            _isDirty = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Transform is a UI related class. I don't think defining a UI related class in ViewModel is a good idea.

Comment: You may want to set [UpdateSourceTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) on your binding to `PropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken.  The `ViewModel` is being notified of the change - i.e. the setter is being called.  For some reason `_symbolTransform` and `value` are equal so   `if (Set(() => SymbolTransform, ref _symbolTransform, value))` is returning false.  No idea how `_symbolTransform` is (apparently) being updated before the setter is called.